# Reading from Firebase Database doesn't work but there is no error message (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have set up the basic `FirebaseDatabase` code and the app runs fine without any error message, but according to the `console.log` the compiler doesn't go in to the actual `Firebase` code as the `console log` TAG can't be found in the `logcat`. Not sure how to trouble shoot this since there is no error message. This is the basic code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
//import com.google.firebase.FirebaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.*
//import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class RecipeGridView : AppCompatActivity() {

   private var db: DatabaseReference? = null
   private var fbdb: FirebaseDatabase? = null
   private var ref: DatabaseReference? = null

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_grid_view)
       Log.d("TAG", "ON CREATE");

       fbdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
       ref = fbdb!!.getReference("cookies")

       ref!!.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {
           override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
            var myDataSnapshot = snapshot!!.getValue()

            Log.d("TAG", "THIS DOESN'T SHOW IN LOGCAT!!!");

            /*for later...
            val children = snapshot!!.children

            print(snapshot.children.count().toString())
            print(p1)

            children.forEach{
                print(it.toString())
            }
    */
        }

        override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {}

        override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot?) {}

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            print(error)
            Log.d("TAG", "ON ERROR");

        }

        override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {}

        }) //END FB CODE
}
}
```

I'm more than happy to post the log, but it's really long and doesn't show any error.

Dependencies are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
```

Also, the maven code is included in the gradle:

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
```

Thoughts on how to proceed are appreciated. Like I said, if it's needed I'll post the log :)

Comment: Try to use Log.e ,

Comment: Still nothing, only the ONCREATE log shows...

Comment: Please check Firebase database RULES. Do you have permission to read/write to your Firebase database?

Comment: Yes, there is permission. I have successfully used the same database with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it now. The code should be in the `onChildAdded()` instead of the `onChildChange()` function. That was it! Got the data now :)